# Why accents are not recognized in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a subject table which has a theme field contains the following rows :

```
theme
-----
pays
économie
associée
```

And I have this basic query :

```
SELECT * FROM SUBJECT WHERE THEME='associée';
```

The query runs fine in Sql developer and returns the expected row to me.
On the other hand under Sqlplus it returns 0 lines to me (which is not normal).
I have the impression that the query does not recognize accented characters under sqlplus. I am thinking of an NLS_LANG problem but I do not know about it. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do these rows look like if you select them?

Comment: Does my post answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your OS session's `NLS_LANG` variable to the value of, e.g., `ENGLISH_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` and restart your SQL Developer. Retry afterwards.

If that didn't help, try also running your query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM SUBJECT WHERE THEME = n'associée';
```

Notice the `n` before the string literal. That's a `nvarchar2` string literal modifier. Depending on your DB charset/national charset settings you may need to explicitly state that the value you are querying for, is "national charset", not just a "regular charset".

If that didn't help, there's actually a multitude of additional variables that come into play when working with accented characters against an Oracle DB.

**Explanation:**
Your SQL Developer *does* recognize accents... provided that you have your Oracle DB session using character set compatible with your database character set. And your Oracle DB session's character set can be set either on OS level (via OS environment variable) or, possibly(!), in SQL Developer's options directly. Alas, the said multitude of other factors may include (though not exclusively):

- your OS regional settings,
- your OS Unicode support,
- your Oracle client software's (SQL Developer) Unicode support,
- your Java JDK/JRE's Unicode support,
- your JDBC driver's Unicode support,
- your other *DBC drivers' Unicode support, if there are any more in chain.

Sad thing is that the more interfaces you have between your keyboard and your Oracle database, the more likely is one of them to fiddle with your charset conversions badly.

So, let's just hope that the first two hints work for you, otherwise I can't help you (that easily).